# __str__ method called on return values of instance methods

Tags: python, string

I am developing a module that draws lines and finds their midpoints. For purposes of testing, I want to create some string outputs from the relevant classes.

```
class Line:
  def __init__(self, endpoints):
    self.start = endpoints[0]
    self.end = endpoints[1]

  def midpoint():
    x = (start.getX + end.getX) / 2.0
    y = (start.getY + end.getY) / 2.0
    return Point(x, y)

  def __str__(self):
    return "line from " + `self.start` + " to " + `self.end` + "."

class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def getX():
    return x

  def getY():
    return y

  def __str__(self):
    return "[" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + "]"

  __repr__ = __str__

point1 = Point(4,5)
point2 = Point(0,0)
line1 = Line([point1, point2])

print line1
print line1.midpoint
```

Expected output:

```
line from [4, 5] to [0, 0]
[2.0, 2.5]
```

Instead I get:

```
line from [4, 5] to [0, 0]
<bound method Line.midpoint of <__main__.Line instance of 0x105064e18>>
```

How can I get the expected string representation of the midpoint, which is being returned as an instance of the Point class?

Comment: You don't call `line1.midpoint`, you're just referencing it. BTW, I thought that noone used the backticks in Python code anymore.

Comment: either call your midpoint (add brackets d'oh) or make it a property...

Comment: @Matthias what should the __str__ method look like without the backticks? (My excuse: I'm accustomed to them from ES6)

Comment: @pgblu You need to use `"` or `'` not  backticks.

Comment: The backticks call `repr` so it would be `repr(self.start)` or you could use the `str(self.start)`. FYI: The backticks are removed in Python 3.

Comment: @pgblu You can use `repr(self.start)` instead of the backticks or use: `return 'line from {!r} to {!r}'.format(self.start, self.end)`

Comment: I clearly have a lot to learn, and took a lot of assumptions from Ruby and/or JS. Thank you.

Comment: Apart from backticks being removed as @Matthias already indicated, `print` as a statement is gone in Python 3 as well. Start adding `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your code and use `print()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the method itself, not the returned value of the method. Change your last line to this:

```
print line1.midpoint()
```

Also, the first definition line of your method should use self as the only parameter, like so:

```
def midpoint(self):
```

The same applies to the rest of the methods, they should have self as a parameter (Point.getX and Point.getY).

Comment: I've tried that. But when I add the parentheses, I get a TypeError: midpoint() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @pgblu You need to add `self` as a parameter. There are also several other errors I see in your code. I suggest you go through it and clean it up.

Comment: But wouldn't `print line1.midpoint()` call `repr` on the returned value? In that case we would need to use `print str(line1.midpoint())`.

Comment: @Matthias Your correct. I belive the OP is confused about what `__repr__` and what `__str__` are for. They're used to give a visual representation of a given object.

Answer (score 1):

In the midpoint method, you should have start.getX(), start.getY(), end.getX(), and end.getY() should have "self." in front of it. You should also have "self" as a parameter for the method for every method in a class.

[midpoint method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3hlo.png)

I will paste the entire code below to show you exactly what I have done.

[entire code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBws4.png)